# How can I replace ' ' with '0' inside a list string in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to import a CSV file with data and then do calculations with the data, the file is made as a list string. I'm trying to replace all the ' ' with '0' in every list that is in the CSV file. Looking for any advice

### My current code:

```
import CSV

with open('Superheroes.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    first_line = csvfile.readline()
    super_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

for vote in super_reader:
    vote.pop(0)
    print(vote)

csvfile.close()
```

---

[image: That is what I'm currently getting]

Comment: I don't think those work because I'm working with lists, not strings... I tried some of their solutions and got an error saying:  'list' object has no attribute 'split'.

Comment: Instead of `data.split(',')` you already have `vote`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
for vote in super_reader:
    list = [(x if x else '0') for x in vote]
    print(list)
```